# Создание RAID 0 из двух флэш карт в windows 8

Tags: windows, администрирование, raid

Добрый день. Есть необходимость в создании RAID-0 массива из двух флэшек. Стандартные средства windows не видят флешки при создании RAID, только usb жесткие диски. Есть ли способ обойти это ограничение или сделать программный рейд другими средствами в windows? Систему на него ставить не будем, просто хранить некоторую БД

P.S Вообще конкретно необходимости в RAID-0 нет, необходимо сделать систему, при которой при извлечении 1 из 2 флешек прочитать данный уже было нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Рейд можно прочитать, если есть специальные знания, оборудование, опыт и собственно цель. В таких случаях лучше воспользоваться шифрованием. Один из вариантов - `TrueCrypt` или его форки, [один из которых](http://veracrypt.codeplex.com/) разрабатывается, кстати на `CodePlex`.

Ещё можно `DiskCryptor`.

Comment: шифровать - плохая идея. Есть есть криптование = значит есть что скрывать. А в случае с RAID0 отдаем 1 флешку и прикидываемся, что она просто сломалась

Comment: Однажды инженер Чжа Вынь обратился к Учителю:

– Один достойный уважения человек сказал мне, что шифровать электронную почту неправильно. Поскольку честному человеку нечего скрывать, шифрованная переписка неизбежно привлечёт внимание Охранительного ведомства. Учитель, что вы об этом думаете?

Инь Фу Во ответил:

– Благородный муж имеет чувство стыдливости. Он закрывает одеждой свою наготу. Вовсе не потому, что лицезрение другими принесёт ему ущерб. Но такова воля Неба, и таков ритуал. Честному человеку есть, что скрывать.

http://forensics.ru/InFuWo.htm

Comment: Кому отдаём флэшку? Уборщице тёте Вале? Ну так она и с 2-ой флэшкой не поймёт, что тут вообще что-то осмысленное есть. Дядечкам в погонах? Вот они как раз всё что есть вытащат, прочитают и предъявят. Тогда дополни вопрос и напиши от кого надо спрятать.

Comment: Да, флэшки я надеюсь на SLC памяти будут?

Comment: флэшки самые обычные, пусть мрут. потеря информации не страшна. Там бд за 3 дня, не более.Прятать от обэп, ищут они бд 1с которую хочу хранить на флэшке. Вот как-то так

Comment: Тогда точно шифрование. Ну и с юристами надо посоветоваться на счёт законов по поводу добровольного раскрытия паролей\ключей.